# Dynamically Loading video from localhost and getting 206 Partial Content

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, video

I am using a simple `react` stack with `redux`. I am then dynamically pulling in data with video locations in from a `google spreadsheet`, this means that I need to import the video files in on the fly:

```
//videoType is the name of the row for videos in the spreadsheet
const videoType = 'outVideo';
const videoData = await import(`../../media/${video[videoType]}`);
this.setState({[videoType]: videoData.default});
```

This also means that video assets are loaded in as soon as the component has rendered but as a promise:

[image]

This will then be loaded into the component and when the time is right display the video (so that we have assets available on the `html5` `video` tag at initiation on the element:

```
      <div className="outVideo">
        {outVideo !== "" &&
          <video
            ref={this[`outVideo${reference}`]}
            autoPlay="autoplay"
            playsInline="playsinline"
          >
            <source
              src={outVideo}
              type="video/mp4"/>
          </video>
        }
      </div>
```

I have just switched from `800kb` files to `95mb` files and while I will get these down, I am curious why the videos just display as `white space` and no video:

[image]

[image]

My understanding is it shouldn't be using 206

Comment: What is the purpose of this? Why do you need dynamic import of video file? That file is reachable by javascript so it is be reachable from html5 video element aswell.

Comment: In most browsers, the video tag will make byte range requests, and 206 is the correct response. The 'white space' is likely unrelated to the 206.

Comment: @bigless the reason is they are dynamically loaded from the spreadsheet and we are including the files locally, IE this will run on a box and only have access to localhost for large assets.

Comment: What "including the files locally" means? That import is just async GET. I still don't understand. Why not just `src="../../media/${video[videoType]}"` and then render/show video tag on `canplay` event?

Comment: I am running a local server, so the assets are served from that local server i `localhost` this means of course http grabs the data but there is no outside request or need of any internet for those assets (videos). The reason for not just putting them inline directly is I need to make sure the video file exists. if it does not, then I remove that `tile`.